# Prove the characteristic function of Cantor set is continuous almost everywhere.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $S \subset \mathbb R$ be a subset of the reals. Define the characteristic function $f_S(x)$ of $S:$ $f_S(x)=\begin{cases} 1,& \text{if $x \in S$}; \\0,& \text{if $x \notin S$.} \end{cases}$
>
> Let $C$ be the Cantor set. Prove that $f_C(x)$ is continuous almost everywhere on $[0,1]$.

My idea is that if a point $x_0$ is not in $\mathbb C$, there is a neighborhood of $x_0$ not in $\mathbb C$. But I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Is the Cantor set closed?

Comment: @fredgoodman  Sorry for my ignorance. Have not learned closed set.

Comment: Well, never mind, then.  Concentrate on the complementary $[0,1] \setminus C$, which is a countable union of open intervals.